# StimulSoft report Experssion Filter doesn't work properly

Tags: stimulsoft

I have a business Object (master that i called Individual) and a Datatable (Details that I called DS) and I wrote a  filter expression for details Databand:

```
DS.UserCode==Individual.UserCode
```

but details of every master record belong to the first master record

if we consider records of UserCode are filled with (1,2,3)
all details Record for each master belong to 1

I think Individual.UserCode is always pointing to the first record of master record

Now what should I do to see the right details for each master record